# How to write two files to disk in a transaction

Tags: c++, qt

I have two files I need to save to disk. If one file fails to save the other absolutely must be erased and vice versa. Is there a way to do this using QT?

Comment: Great question! Might either QTempararyFile or QSaveFile help towards this? I'm not aware of something in Qt that provides an atomic operation concept over multiple files but perhaps you could build something like that out of Qt code. I think that'd also depend on exactly the level of atomicity you need. Qt can only provide what the OS/kernel/hardware it's running on gives it access to of course.

Comment: How about using QSaveFile with a multi-file format like zip or tar? That way `commit` transactionally persists both or neither which sounds like what you're looking for. Of course the actual file then is the one multi-file-formatted file instead of the two separate ones.

Comment: Good thinking. I will try it out

Comment: If the files must be separate, on normal file systems it’s impossible to *absolutely* guarantee such things because of fatal signals and power failures.